# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils, maven pom.xml wa

Tags: java, maven, exception, pom.xml, war

I know someone else has asked this similar question before, but it's not the same. I solved my problem by removing war in the maven pom.xml. what's going on behind the scene?  Why does it complain ClassNotFoundException? [image]

Comment: WAR and JAR (Maven's default type) are two different packaging formats. how are you running this?

Answer (score 2):

MoJoExecutionException is exceptions by maven plugins to signle something is wrong. reading you error stacktrace looks like your tomcat plugin is complaining about class not found at runtime.

can you please share your complete `pom.xml`. Have you added tomcat plugin ?

Also add below dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks. it will build but when the maven module runs, it will throw Cast Exception which maybe caused by another problem

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. 
I finally partly found my own problem.
[image: pom.xml of my maven module]

I changed dubbo version from 2.8.4 (which I maven packaged from github myself) to 2.5.3, which turned out to work.
There is no need to use Common IO jar as dependency any more whether the module is packaged as jar or war here. maybe can be helpful to someone else who happens to run to the same issue